# Anonymous user cannot see a user defined folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-config, authorization

In my root website, there is a folder named **Styles** which is being located at the same level with App_Themes folder as the image shown some lines below.

And in my web.config file, the setting of the authorization node is

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />      
</authorization>
```

OK, now if I log in the website with an authenticated user, I can see my Styles folder.
[image]

BUT, the anonymous user can NOT see it.

[image]

I understood the reason of this behavior due to the  setting in the configuration file.

However, I also want the anonymous user can see the Styles folders too while still using the setting of  node. And I don't want to move the Styles folder into App_Themes.

I tried to Google to find solution that can solve it. But, I get unlucky.

Is there any way can do it? Please give me some advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about this question anymore, guys.

I found a solution that I just create a web.config file and put it into the Styles folder.

The content of the configuration file

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```